# Set the checkbox of a CheckboxTableViewer when the row is clicked

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, actionlistener, jface

I am very new to SWT. Started working on it today actually. I have a table of type CheckboxTableViewer. What i want to be able to do is whenever the user selects the row (i.e clicks anywhere on the row) I want the check box to be checked (ticked). Currently I have a listener on the CheckboxTableViewer as follows:

```
diagnosesTableViewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {

            Nomenclature changedStateNomenclature = (Nomenclature) event
                    .getElement();
            if (event.getChecked()) {
                selectedNomenclatures.add(changedStateNomenclature);
            } else {
                selectedNomenclatures.remove(changedStateNomenclature);
            }
        }

    });
```

I am able to select the row by checking on the checkbox. But i want to select the check box even when the user selects the row by clicking anywhere on that row on any column (not just the checkbox).

I guess that logic would go somewhere in the `addSelectionChangedListener` for the addSelectionChangedListener. But I am not sure how to go about it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code: Add selection listener to the table. `ctv` is the instance of of your `CheckboxTableViewer`.

Also I assumed `CheckboxTableViewer` allow only single selection not multi.

```
ctv.getTable().addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      int df = ctv.getTable().getSelectionIndex();
      ctv.setChecked(ctv.getElementAt(df), !ctv.getChecked(ctv.getElementAt(df)));
  }         
});
```

Comment: You can use `SelectionAdapter` instead of `SelectionListener` to avoid having to code `widgetDefaultSelected`.

Comment: I am running into a problem with this. When I click on the row, it works as expected but when I click on the checkbox, I does not remove the focus from the previously clicked row and hence it changes the state of that row along with the new row that I am clicking. Is there a way I can remove the focus from the previously selected row and change it to the row whose checkbox I am clicking?

Comment: Ask new question with adding table viewer code. I am not able to understand properly.