# Set the checkbox of a CheckboxTreeViewer when the row is clicked

Tags: java, checkbox, swt, rcp

I'm looking for a generic approach to check the checkbox of CheckBoxTreeViewer, when the row / the item is selected.
I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267230/set-the-checkbox-of-a-checkboxtableviewer-when-the-row-is-clicked) regarding the CheckBoxTableViewer, which answer helped me, but it doesn't apply to the CheckBoxTreeViewer. I assume, I have to use the ISelectionChangedListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the grayed state by calling the CheckStateListener, which is responsible to maintain the checked and grayed state of the elements.

```
public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) {
    Object selection = ((StructuredSelection) event.getSelection()).getFirstElement();
    if (selection != null) {
        boolean state = !checkboxTreeViewer.getChecked(selection);
        checkboxTreeViewer.setChecked(selection, state);
        checkboxTreeViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
        checkStateListener.checkStateChanged(new CheckStateChangedEvent((ICheckable) event.getSource(), selection,
            state));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an ISelectionChangedListener and receive the selected object from the SelectionChangedEvent. Then you can set the checked state for this object like this:

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            Object selection = ((StructuredSelection)event.getSelection()).getFirstElement();
            viewer.setChecked(selection, true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That works generally, but I'm having problems with a multi-level tree, where I'm using the "grayed" state, if some of the subelements are checked and some not.